Formula Image doesn't display for certain users
I have created formula field to display icon based on other field value (severity of case). Recently when one of users were screen sharing I saw that instead of image he saw text e.g. Major.
Formula:
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(Priority, 'Major') , 
    IMAGE("imgURL", "Major", 25, -1),
    IF(
        ISPICKVAL(Priority, 'Critical'), 
        IMAGE("imgURL", "Critical", 25, -1), 
        IF(
            ISPICKVAL(Priority, 'Minor'), 
            IMAGE("imgURL", "Minor", 30, -1),
            ''
        )
    )
)

Also I noticed that during screen share quality of video was poor. Is it possible that for some users with weak internet connection images will not be displayed?

Hi there! Where is the image hosted, please?

That's always a possibility. You can't download files without the Internet. But to be sure, you should have the user open the browser's F12 Developer Console, and check out the Network tab. This will indicate the nature of the problem (e.g. 404 for file not found, 403 for unauthorized, etc). It may also be the user doesn't have access to that resource, e.g. if it's a Salesforce File and isn't shared with that user.

Liam Gatt,
production org -> files -> Libraries -> folder

sfdcfox,
Thanks for info i will check network tab with user during screen share
